# Windows authentication on web.api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a self-hosted Web API application (the server application) that uses Windows authentication.

Windows Auth is enabled in `Startup.cs/Configuration` by setting the following AuthenticationSchemes on `System.Net.HttpListener`

```
System.Net.HttpListener listener = (System.Net.HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication 
                    | System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
```

And Controllers then use the [Authorize] tag. I can then extract the `Principal.Identity` from the `HttpRequestContext` for every controller method to see who’s making the call.

It appears this is only working if the caller and server are on the same host. As soon as the calling application is on another host, all requests are blocked with a 401 unauthorized and no controller method is ever hit on the server. This is even if the calling application is executed under the same user account that the server. So is there a special config required so Windows authentication on web.api works across different machines?

Regards meisterd

Comment: Edit: I tried to do some traces with Fiddler, and if Fiddler is enabled, the requests seem to work (I see three Request that are performed)

Comment: Is there a Proxy, other than Fiddler, between those machines and the server? Because NTLM/Kerberos don't allow authentication throu Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

In the Startup class of your WebAPI, add a call to use CORS. You may need to add Microsoft.Owin to you packages if you don't already have it. This should allow access to your api from other hosts.

It should look something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        //... Your other startup code

        appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Comment: We'll try that shortly. I just had a look at wireshark traces from a working (fiddler active) and non working request - the difference being I see KRB Error: KRB5KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED in the non working example. That seems to indicate there's some kind of Kerberos problem. Weird that it goes away when Fiddler is running.